# SQL Packager error : Database version 'a.b.c' not supported

Tags: sql, redgate

We are trying to upgrade the database from 2.8.1 to 2.9.0, while doing so thru' SQL Packager tool we get error: Database version '2.8.2' not supported. Am quite new to it and not sure how to resolve this and where to get more details from. The tool was working fine till now for lower versions. Any leads in resolving this is much appreciated!!

Comment: Which database product are you talking about? (SQL is just a query language, not a DBMS product)

Comment: [SQL Packager](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-packager/) is a now retired Red Gate product.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned issue is resolved. It was due to presence of older version of scripts.